# Keep process running 24/7 EC2

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, daemon

I have a script that I need to be running 24/7. However, I cannot seem to get EC2 to stop killing the process

I've tried daemonizing it with `python-daemon`,
I've tried `nohup`,
I've tried adding `&` at the end of the command to make it a background process,
I've tried `screen` to assign it to a virtual session.

All of these work temporarily but when I check it an hour later with `ps aux | grep python`, it's no longer there/no longer running

I've looked at the output and the nohup.out file to see if it's crashing because of an error but no error/output

I've used signal handlers:

```py
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)
```

Still nothing. I suspected that there may be an error that is escaping my tests but I ran it in an open console for an hour and it worked perfectly so there must be something unexpected happening unassociated to my code.

An excerpt:

```py
import signal
import time
from daemon import DaemonContext

import schedule as schedule


global exit_now


def exit_gracefully(*args):
    global exit_now
    exit_now = True


def run_server():
    global exit_now

    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(lambda: a_function(param1, param2))
    schedule.every(3).hours.do(lambda: another_function(param1, param2))
    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(function_with_no_params)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)

    exit_now = False
    while not exit_now:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    my_model.backup()
    print("Processes successfully stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with DaemonContext():
        run_server()
```

Edit: I tried adding a log file to my daemon and to my nohup to catch and print whatever's breaking it but upon exit, nothing. No output at all. Additionally, I tried disowning the background process but that didn't work.

The OS is Amazon Linux. Here's a link to the codebase in case you would like to reproduce it: https://github.com/DavidTeju/Tweet-Generator

Comment: Would it work to use cron to schedule runs instead?  That's more reliable since processes can "go bad" through resource leaks, heap fragmentation, and crashes from bugs.

Comment: maybe a heartbeat function which checks if alove and if not alive then restart.

Comment: Are you redirecting the output to a log?  Make sure you capture stdout and stderr (something like `python myfile.py >>log 2>&1` but check that).  The EC2 will not kill the process.  But running out of memory or having an error in your code could.

Comment: Adding to @D.L's idea, some kind of health check that the process is running and still doing work, not just running while trapped in some failed state.

Comment: @DaveS How can I do the health check if EC2 keeps shutting that down. Wouldn't that (health check) shut down as well? Remember, the process isn't just running dead weight. The process stops running entirely

Comment: there is an EC2 keep alive:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-timeout.html

Comment: @D.L That's just timeout for a session. Max is 60 mins so that wouldn't work for keeping it alive 24/7

Comment: For the health check I was thinking about a cron job that runs every x minutes to see if the process is still there (as @D.L suggests) but also looks for something the main app does as a sign that it is still completing work.  For example if it appends to a completed-work-results..log file.